# Dynamically Changing Color of myDBR Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: mydbr

Good Morning,

I need to dynamically set the colors of segments of bars in a MyDBR Stacked Bar Chart.  My task is to display the elapsed times that different engines have on or off over the course of a day.

I almost have what I need in a stacked bar chart using just the first three fields, [here](http://www.mleary2001.com/stackedBarChart.png)  However, I need the 'on' segments of a bar to be green, and the 'off' segments to be red, based on the values in a fourth field, 'Ignition'.

I have a MySQL procedure that returns a result set with four fields:

```
Engine   DateTime              Elapsed    Ignition
111      2015-01-02 01:03:12   01:03:15   On
```

I think I almost have the answer with the following code:

select distinct 'dbr.chart.options', 'bar_segment???', Ignition, '0xFF0000'from resultset??? where Ignition = 'Off'

select distinct 'dbr.chart.options', 'bar_segment???', Ignition, '0x00FF00'from resultset??? where Ignition = 'Off'

Any help will be much appreciated,

mleary2001

Answer (score 0):

Got some great help from the myDBR folks to come up with the answer.

```
/* call stored procedure to make myTable, described above */
CALL stored_procedure;

/*myDBR chart code */
select 'dbr.chart', 'StackedBar';
select 'dbr.chart.options', 'label_color', DateTime, if (Ignition='On', '0x42B64A^', '0xE85854') from myTable;

/* select data from the temp table created above */
SELECT
    Asset,
    event_date,
    Elapsed,
    Ignition
FROM
    myTable;
```

This results in a Stacked Bar Chart with the bar segments dynamically colored as required. :)